# Mostrar Tooltip (hover) con CSS dentro de los límites de la ventana del navegador

Tags: css3, hover, tooltip

Al pasar con el ratón por encima de un texto, quiero que se muestre un `tooltip` (`div`) con una tabla que almacena información. Esta funcionalidad la hace correctamente, salvo que depende de dónde se encuentre el texto, al hacer `hover`, el `tooltip` se sale por los bordes de la ventana.

¿Cómo puedo evitar que el `div` se muestre fuera del área visible? Me gustaría trabajar con CSS, pero no me importa que haya una solución alternativa con Javascript.

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
 
.tooltiptext, .tooltipTable {
 min-width: 200px;
 font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
 <h2>Title</h2>
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
 <div class="tooltiptext">
  <table class="tooltipTable" border="1">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Text: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Text: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Text: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Text: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Text: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Text: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Estas usando algún script de boostrap?

Comment: No, no estoy usando bootstrap. Lo intenté pero sólo aceptan texto y necesito añadir código html al tooltip (<table>, <div>, ...)

Comment: Puedes añadir también código html solo que tienes que especificar que es html y ademas en ves de usa "" usas ''.